# How To Implement Multi-Tenant In Loopback

Tags: multi-tenant, loopbackjs

We're using Loopback for our REST endpoints and need to implement a multi-tenant capability. All of our tables have 'tenantid'. We have our own user model and do not use the Loopback user model. Is there a way to **capture all inbound requests and verify or update the tenantid on-the-fly**? The goal is to ensure that all 'get' requests be appended with something like **'filter[where][tenantid]=tenantid'** and all save oriented requests have 'tenantid' populated properly.

Comment: I would consider a [dynamic role resolver(s)](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles#Definingandusingroles-Dynamicroles). There is a [third-party loopback component package](https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-component-access-groups) available, which enables you to add multi-tenant style access controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the ['parse' middleware](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Defining+middleware) in your server.js and modify the filter for all requests on the fly:

```
app.middleware('parse', parse)

function parse(req, res, next) {
    // Add an 'and' filter that specifies the tenant in all requests. 
    req.query.filter.where.and.push({ tenantid: 283 });
}
```